# Can someone explain the console output of this program?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package com.threads;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> map = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
        for(Thread s: map.keySet()){
            System.out.println(s + Arrays.toString(map.get(s)));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestThread testThread = new TestThread();
        Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> map = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
        for(Thread s: map.keySet()){
            System.out.println(s + Arrays.toString(map.get(s)));
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        testThread.start();     
    }

}
```

```
Thread[main,5,main][java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads(Native Method), java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Unknown Source), com.threads.TestThread.main(TestThread.java:17)]
Thread[Finalizer,8,system][java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source), java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source), java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)]
Thread[Reference Handler,10,system][java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source), java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)]
Thread[Attach Listener,5,system][]
Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system][]

---------------------------------
Thread[Thread-0,5,main][java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads(Native Method), java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Unknown Source), com.threads.TestThread.run(TestThread.java:8)]
Thread[Finalizer,8,system][java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source), java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source), java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)]
Thread[Reference Handler,10,system][java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source), java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)]
Thread[Attach Listener,5,system][]
Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system][]
```

Since I started a new thread, I expected to find another entry in the Map I am printing. But the number of threads remained the same.

Answer (score 3):

The number stays the same, but a new thread has appeared: Thread-0, and another one has disappeared: main.

That's expected, since the main thread exits as soon as the main method returns, and Thread-0 is the thread you have started.

Answer (score 1):

Number of threads is the same, as your main thread has already completed the job at the point where `TestThread` is accessing `Thread.getAllStackTraces()`.

In the main thread, you can [join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) and wait for the `TestThread` to complete.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    TestThread testThread = new TestThread();
    Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> map = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
    for(Thread s: map.keySet()){
        System.out.println(s + Arrays.toString(map.get(s)));
    }
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    testThread.start();     
    testThread.join();
}
```

Which yields following output:

```
Thread[main,5,main][java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads(Native Method), java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Unknown Source), code.TestThread.main(TestThread.java:17)]
Thread[Attach Listener,5,system][]
Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system][]
Thread[Reference Handler,10,system][java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503), java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)]
Thread[Finalizer,8,system][java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source), java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source), java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)]
-----------------------------------------
Thread[main,5,main][java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.Thread.join(Unknown Source), java.lang.Thread.join(Unknown Source), code.TestThread.main(TestThread.java:23)]
Thread[Attach Listener,5,system][]
Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system][]
Thread[Thread-0,5,main][java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads(Native Method), java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Unknown Source), code.TestThread.run(TestThread.java:8)]
Thread[Reference Handler,10,system][java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503), java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)]
Thread[Finalizer,8,system][java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source), java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source), java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)]
```

Comment: 5 is priority and `main` thread group name.
You can lookup the source code for `java.lang.Thread.toString()`: `return ("Thread[" + name + "," + priority + "," (group == null ? "" : group.getName()) + "]");`

Comment: Got it ...Thanks a lot